# How Can I Force SSL in nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I need to redirect all traffic from http://mydomain.com to ?

What is the right way to do this in nginx?

Comment: Please refine your question, I do not get what you want to achieve

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx

Answer (score 4):

Does this do the trick?

```
rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
```