# How to force or redirect to SSL in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, ruby-on-rails

I have a signup page on a subdomain like: `https://signup.example.com`

It should only be accessible via HTTPS but I'm worried people might somehow stumble upon it via HTTP and get a 404.

My html/server block in nginx looks like this:

```
html {
  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name signup.example.com;

    ssl                        on;
    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;

    ssl_session_timeout 30m;

    location / {
      root /path/to/my/rails/app/public;
      index index.html;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
  }
}
```

What can I add so that people who go to `http://signup.example.com` get redirected to `https://signup.example.com` ? (FYI I know there are Rails plugins that can force `SSL` but was hoping to avoid that)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Nginx, how can I rewrite all http requests to https while maintaining sub-domain?](http://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

According to [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites), it's slightly better to omit the unnecessary capture, using `$request_uri` instead. In that case, append a question mark to prevent nginx from doubling any query args.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name signup.mysite.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Or, according to the site you linked, *"BETTER"*: `return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;`

Comment: one comment. the $server_name$ picks up the first server_name variable. So be aware of this if you have non FQN names in your configuration

Comment: @nh2 This is another case of the documentation being wrong since using `return 301...` causes a "too many redirects" error while the rewrite method actually works.

Comment: That's now documented as "also BAD". @MikeBethany `return 301` does work, unless (I guess) you're triggering it *also* for correct URLs, by listening on both ports (example of config. triggering the problem: take http://serverfault.com/a/474345/29689's first answer and omit the if).

Comment: @Blaisorblade Thanks, that's a much better way to do it.

Comment: It's probably wise to `listen [::]:80;` in addition so as to bind/redirect on IPv6 also.

Comment: I wonder what has changed over the years and whether this other answer is better: https://serverfault.com/a/337893/119666

Answer (score 278):

The best way as it described in [the official how-to](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) is by using the [`return`](http://nginx.org/r/return) directive:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name signup.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: shortest answer and worked perfectly in my case

Comment: This is generally recommended because it returns a `301 Moved Permanently` (your links have permanently moved) as well as re-writing

Comment: This doesn't work as it causes a "too many redirects" error even if you have set `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;`

Comment: @MikeBethany are you defining `listen 443;` in the same block?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If you use CloudFlare, turn forced HTTPS under the Crypto tab.

Comment: Administrators that are commit to run HTTPS only servers should also consider enable HTST header so that modern clients knows that all future requests targeted at that domain must be performed over HTTPS. In nginx, this can be done by adding the line `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;` to the corresponding HTTPS block.

Answer (score 134):

This is the correct and most efficient way if you want to keep it all in one server block:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen   443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Everything else above, using "rewrite" or "if ssl_protocol" etc is slower and worse.

Here is the same, but even more efficient, by only running the rewrite on the http protocol it avoids having to check the $scheme variable on every request. But seriously, it's such a minor thing that you don't need to separate them.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;
}
```

Comment: Great, some coward voted this answer down without saying why, even though this answer is correct. Maybe another one of those "if is evil" cultists. If you bother to read the Nginx documentation about If, you will know that IfIsNOTEvil, just CERTAIN uses of it within a location{} context, none of which we do here. My answer is absolutely the correct way of doing things!

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but I would like to point out that default has been changed to 'default_server' in the most recent versions.

Comment: The first solution cannot be the most efficient, if the second one is even more efficient. And you even described, why you shouldn't use an if there: "it avoids having to check the $scheme variable on every request". The point of not using ifs is not only about performance, but also about being declarative, and not imperative.

Comment: +1 for if ($scheme = http)

Comment: Should use $host here, as mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($scheme" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com:16`

Answer (score 55):

If you are using the new dual HTTP and HTTPS server definition, you can use the following:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen   443 default ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

This appears to work for me and doesn't cause redirect loops.

**Edit:**

Replaced:

```
rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
```

with Pratik's rewrite line.

Comment: @DavidPashley your solution worked like a charm for me.
Thanks

Comment: `If you are using the new dual HTTP and HTTPS server definition` then you should separate it.

Comment: elegant and works perfect!

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me with my Laravel/Homestead Nginx configuration.

Comment: Also the rewrite line ought to be `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;` as this is the preferred method.

Comment: For completeness, one might add: `listen   [::]:443 ssl;`

Answer (score 31):

Yet another variant, that preserves the Host: request header and follows the "GOOD" example on [nginx pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites):

```
server {
    listen   10.0.0.134:80 default_server;

    server_name  site1;
    server_name  site2;
    server_name  10.0.0.134;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Here are the results. Note that using `$server_name` instead of `$host` would always redirect to `https://site1`.

```
# curl -Is http://site1/ | grep Location
Location: https://site1/

# curl -Is http://site2/ | grep Location
Location: https://site2/


# curl -Is http://site1/foo/bar | grep Location
Location: https://site1/foo/bar

# curl -Is http://site1/foo/bar?baz=qux | grep Location
Location: https://site1/foo/bar?baz=qux
```

Comment: `Note that using $server_name instead of $host would always redirect to https://site1` isn't that what `$request_uri` is for?

Comment: `$request_uri` does not contain a host or domain name. In other words, it always starts with a "/" character.

Comment: Best answer by far.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer is so low in votes. It's the only one worth using.

Comment: Cant believe so many people use $server_name this is the correct way to do it

Comment: Both $host and $server_name are correct, in different environments. $host reuses the hostname used in the client URL; $server_name forces a redirect to the correct, canonical hostname of the site. For most uses I prefer server_name.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most simple solution. Forces both non-HTTPS and non-WWW traffic to HTTPS and www only.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

    # global HTTP handler
    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
    }

    # global non-WWW HTTPS handler
    if ($http_host = domain.tld) {
        return 303 https://www.domain.tld$request_uri;
    }
}
```

EDIT - Apr 2018: Solution w/o IF's can be found in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777526/6076984

Comment: Aren't IF conditions considered evil and inefficient in the nginx world?

Comment: Yes they are, in general. But for this simple checks I would guess not. I do have a proper configuration file which involves more code writing though, but avoids IF's completely.

Comment: Google advises to use 301 instead of 303.
Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en

Comment: @DylanHunt - I left 303 only for testing, take a note that 1st handler was set to 301, only 2nd I forgot to change :) Also, solution w/o IF's: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777526/6076984

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen x.x.x.x:80;

    server_name domain.tld;
    server_name www.domian.tld;
    server_name ipv4.domain.tld;

    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This works better i think. x.x.x.x refers to your server's IP. If you are working with Plesk 12, you can do that by changing the "nginx.conf" file in the directory "/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.tld/conf" for whichever domain you want. Do not forget to restart nginx service after you save the configuration.

Comment: `rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent; `
would be a better solution as you might have several server names on a vhost