# ssl 301 redirect for nginx and wordpress

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

What would be the best method to load https in wordpress for a specific url? I'm using events manager pro and would like to have the event pages load securely with out using a plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault! Please update your question to be more specific. Do you want to use Nginx automatically issue a 301 redirect for some http:// URLs to https versions of the same page? Providing an example of the case you are trying to cover could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you describing the same case as [How to force or redirect to SSL in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx).

This sounds like it may be a duplicate question. Otherwise, please provide specifics of how your case is different.

Comment: Then please provide specifics of how your case is different. Exactly what did you try, and what was the result you desired, and what was the result that happened instead?

Comment: My site loads on both http and https w/out error. When a user loads this page(s) mysite.com/adventures I would like https to activate. since there is form accepting credit cards. Although it forces https behind the scenes I think people are traine to see the https lock when shopping online. thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to redirect GET requests or POST requests? POST requests can't be redirected. Otherwise, why not use a standard Nginx redirect syntax?