# How can I redirect HTTP traffic to an absolute link path with iptables?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to redirect a host to a specific link on my network when they try to browse through HTTP.

The IP address of the host I'm trying to redirect is `192.168.2.19` and my web-server is on `192.168.2.15:6969/test.js`. When I redirect the user I can only get him to `192.168.2.15:6969` and not the relative path. I tried specifying in the `iptables` command but it did not work.

Here's what I did:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.2.19 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT 
--to-destination 192.168.2.15:3000/test.js
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with iptables. You're trying to perform an HTTP redirect, so you'll need to perform the redirect using an application that speaks HTTP, like apache or [nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx/250488#250488).