# HTTPS redirect enforcement

Tags: ssl, http

Are there some automatic free tools for enforcing http->https redirect which dosen't affect the ht.access file ?
Thanks for any suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Automatic Free Tools" and "Server Administration" usually don't go together. "Automatic Tools" are usually tools that do a task the user might want to do, but which is complicated to do manually, such as reading out hard drive parameters, dumping an audio CD to a file, etc.

When administrating a server, you are expected to know what you are doing, at least to some degree. So, let's work on that and get you up to speed, so you know what you are doing!

#### Why you want to redirect to HTTPS

HTTP is insecure, but - at least for now - the default when visiting an address in your browser. When you go to `stackexchange.com`, your browser will default<sup>1</sup> to communicating with port 80 and expect a plain HTTP response.

An attacker with Man-in-the-Middle capabilities can intercept this plain HTTP response and just insert "whatever" there, such as malicious JavaScript, a malware download, etc...

As such, you want to make sure that your users spend as little time as possible on insecure HTTP pages and redirect to HTTPS pages immediately.

#### How do redirects work?

When a browser visits a HTTP site, you can send a 301 response instead, together with the same site, but HTTPS. This tells the browser to navigate to that page instead. All modern browsers honor such a request.

For example, in nginx, the server configuration to do that looks as follows:

```
server {
   listen 800;
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$hostname$request_uri;
}
```

This will take a request going to `http://example.com/foo/bar` and redirect it to `https://example.com/foo/bar`

#### Is this enough?

No, it's not. As you see, the redirect is still sent in plain text. The attacker can still modify this and prevent the user from ever reaching the HTTPS site.

As such, the [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) header was created. What this header does is to instruct the browser that every future call should be in HTTPS - even if HTTP was *explicitly* requested.

But that still leaves the very first view of the site unprotected. In order to mitigate that, your site should be added to a [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/). The idea here is that the server tells the preload list that they support HSTS and will always support HSTS. When the browser navigates to the domain the first time, they check if the domain is in the preload list, and if so, automatically navigate to HTTPS instead. Plain HTTP is never used.

#### What about other solutions?

JavaScript redirects can be used, but they don't really protect you any better than a HTTP 301 redirect. In fact, they're worse, because they require the user to download and execute JavaScript, instead of one simple, bodiless HTTP response.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it will check its HSTS cache first, but we'll skip that for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it at the [page level with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723213/detect-http-or-https-then-force-https-in-javascript), but note the top comment to that question, which says it's more reliable and more efficient to do it at the server level.

.htaccess is one way to do it at the server level, but of course utilizing the server config is preferred over .htaccess.  Here's how to do it with [Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/how-to-automatically-redirect-http-to-https-on-apache-servers) or [Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx).